# Why doesn't a permanent magnetic field not make a florescent light illuminate like an electromagnet field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, visible-light, magnetic-fields

Similar to this question: [What is the difference between the magnetic field of a permanent magnet, and that of an electromagnet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197575/what-is-the-difference-between-the-magnetic-field-of-a-permanent-magnet-and-tha) mine is different because I want to know why a permanent magnet with the same field intensity does not light up a fluorescent light like these pictures below with an electromagnetic field? Can a permanent magnet be made to make a florescent light illuminate by adding a current to the permanent magnet?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A permanent magnetic field does not transfer kinetic energy to charge carriers like an applied electric field in a gas discharge tube. Thus electrons are not able to impact ionize or excite atoms so that they can emit light that would bring the fluorescent material in a discharge tube to fluorescence.

Comment: is there an illustration of that?

Comment: @jen - What do you mean by illustration? A picture?

Comment: it helps me visualize the difference.

Comment: @jen - Sorry I don't have any picture of this. The main point is that electrons and ions experience a force in a magnetic field, the Lorentz force, which is always perpendicular to the velocity and to the magnetic field, Therefore no energy is gained by the charge carriers in a magnetic field. The energy gain of charge carriers in an electric field causes the excitation or ionization of atoms in high energy collisions with charge carriers that leads to light emission. Fluorescent coatings are used to improve the visible light emission efficiency of common gas discharge tubes.